# Can I compile f90 without recreating .mod files

Tags: module, compilation, fortran, gfortran, object-files

I am a newbie in fortran and I am trying to understand all I need for the compilation. Until now everything is good but there is something I don't get. Supposing that I modify the code but my modifications wouldn't change the content of the .mod files, am I able to compile and create the object file **without** recreating the .mod file, and if yes how should I do it. I tried to search on the internet but I didn't really manage to find the answer. By the way, I am using gfortran.
Thank you in advance and I am sorry if the answer already exists (I couldn't find it).

Comment: Are you using any build system such as a Makefile or something similar? Are you asking how to avoid unneded recompilation? Can you show an example (not thhe code, just commands) of what you are doing?

Comment: @VladimirF Unfortunaly I cannot show an example, but that's exactly what I wand to do, avoid unneeded recompilation since it's a huge program and in total it takes approximately 4 minutes to compile. Yes a Makefile is being used!

Comment: In that case you do have to show an example. See [ask] and [mcve]. Be aware that there are other more modern build systems, some targeted specifically to Fortran. Basically this is an XY problem, you do not actually need to avoid recreating a mod file, you need to avoid the recompilation.

Comment: @VladimirF you are right I should show part of it but unfortunately it is confidential and it is a program used by a lot of people so it won't be possible at least not in the near future to use another build system. I am only doing an internship for 2 months and I don't have the right to say much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using gfortran, the compiler already does this for you. When compiling a module, it will create the `.mod` file under a temporary name, then it will compare checksums between the existing `.mod` file (if it exists) and the new one, and replace the existing one with the new one only if the checksums differ.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.Alright but is there a way to tell gfortran to not create these `.mod` at all? I do not waste time on the recreation of the `.mod` files

Comment: Have you profiled and verified that writing that `.mod` file takes up a significant portion of the entire compilation time for that source file?

Comment: No I haven't tested that yet and I can't find how to generate only the `.mod` files :'( The total compilation time is 4m19s approx

Comment: The problem though is that the code is developed by phd students and researchers and they need to compile many times sometimes and it can be a real "waste" of time. That's why they need to reduce the time to the minimum

Comment: If you want to only generate the `.mod` file but not the `.o`, thus saving some time, you can use the `-fsyntax-only` option.

Comment: One usecase for using `-fsyntax-only` to speed up compilation would be to first do one pass with that, thus generating all the `.mod` files needed, then a second pass doing the "real" build which can then be done with more parallelism. Whether that is worth it depends on the project.

Comment: More generally, to speedup builds, make sure you have the dependencies in the makefile correct. In particular, if you specify the dependencies on `.mod` files rather than the `.o` files, the gfortran feature mentioned in this answer helps avoid recompilation cascades.

Another common trick is to have a 'debug build' option that enables various error checking options and has much lower optimization level, enabling faster builds (at the cost of runtime performance).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try that!